# SSL overweight in Java

Tags: java, ssl

I'm using org.apache.commons.ssl to make an SSL server in Java.
I'm facing a strange problem : I send 500KB of data over the SSL stream, I receive 500KB of data on client side, but the transferred data over the TCP connection is 20 times bigger.
What could be the cause ? A bad configuration of SSL parameters ?

I'm using a real trusted SSL certificate for my tests.
I tried to sniff and decode the SSL stream with Wireshark but it didn't work, I wasn't able to see the decoded data. Or maybe the stream was encoded in more than one pass ?
The TCP packets were 1525 bytes each. Nothing abnormal as I could see.

If somebody has an idea ...
Thanks !
Olivier

Comment: How often are you calling `flush()` on the stream? You may want to post the code that is writing data to the socket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renegotiations won't account for your 20x explosion. Are you using `BufferedOutputStreams` around the SSL socket's output streams *in both directions?* i.e. at the server *and* the client? If you don't use buffered output and your code writes one byte at a time you can see a 40x explosition due to the SSL record protocol, and, geometrically, *another* 40x explosition due to TCP segment overhead; the latter is usually mitigated by the Nagle algorithm, but some people turn that off, a little too keenly IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you are only sending one byte at a time over the wire.  The overhead is then the TCP/IP-packet encapsulation.

Comment: The overhead is SSL record encapsulation, right? 1 byte of application data in each SSL record.

Comment: Could be.  I am not familiar with the internals of SSL.

Comment: Hi,
That's what I tought first, but it's not the case. The writing to the socket is done using a BufferedOutputStream over the SSL socket, and the flush() method is called once after the 500K are written.
Using Wireshark I could see that each TCP packet was around 1400 bytes (can't remember exact number).
It seems the problem only occurs in one direction : from server to client (download), but not from client to server (upload).
Using openssl to test my app from shell, I see some strange stuff about "renegociation". Any idea ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

@EJP: you were right, I made a mistake in my code: I was wrapping a `BufferedOuputStream` around a `SomeStuffOutputStream`, instead of wrapping a `SomeStuffOutputStream` around `BufferedOuputStream`.
The `BufferedOuputStream` must be at the lowest level, just above the raw socket's `OutputStream`.

Now it's working perfectly!

It was a misconception, and I'm just beginning to understand why I saw "normal" packet sizes, because SSL protocol stuff. I'll be more careful next time :)

Thanks to all.

Comment: THis explanation traditionally goes in an edit in the original question, not as a separate answer.